# Move a 2D square on y-axis on Android GLES2

Tags: android, opengl-es2

I am trying to create a simple game for Android. To start, I am trying to make the square move down the y-axis, but the way I am doing it, it doesn't move the square at all and I can't find any tutorials for GLES20.

The `onDrawFrame` function in the `render` class updates the user's position based on acceleration due to gravity, gets the transform matrix from the `user` class which is used to move the square down, then the program draws it.

All that happens is that the square is drawn; no motion happens:

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) 
{
    user.update(0.0, phy.AccelerationDewToGravity);
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // Re draws black background

    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maPositionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 12, user.SquareVB);//triangleVB);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maPositionHandle);
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(maPositionHandle, 1, false, user.getTransformMatrix(), 0);

    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

}
```

The `update` function in the `player` class is

```
public void update(double vh, double vv)
{
    Vh += vh; // Increase horrzontal Velosity
    Vv += vv; // Increase vertical velosity

    //Matrix.translateM(mMMatrix, 0, (int)Vh, (int)Vv, 0);
    Matrix.translateM(mMMatrix, 0, mMMatrix, 0, (float)Vh, (float)Vv, 0);
}
```

Comment: Its been too long since ive done anything with OpenGL ES so I cant offer a good solution, but here is a link to a site that gives decent tutorials http://www.learnopengles.com/

Comment: I don't see any interaction between GLES20 and you mMMatrix object.